# iframe with # in the src attribute not loading in Firefox

Tags: firefox, iframe

The below iframe will display in every browser except Firefox. Any insight as to why?

```
<iframe src="http://sitename.com/directory/#pagename/"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with firefox doing either some url decoding or looking at window.location.hash rather than window.location.href. The hash in the url was stubbing part of url needed to load the iframe properly.

Changing the src attribute to http://sitename.com/directory#pagename/ solved the problem.